# How can templates with inheritance explicitly call their parent's constructor?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

If I have a toy class inheritance like:

```
template <typename ModelT>
class Parent {
public:
  Parent(int i) {}
};

template <typename ModelT>
class Child : public Parent<ModelT> {
public:
  Child(int i) : Parent(i) {}
};

int main() {
  Child<int> c(42);
}
```

How can I explicitly invoke `Parent`'s `Parent<ModelT>(i)` constructor?  As it is, if I invoke g++ 5.2.1 with

```
g++ -std=c++14 ~/tmp.cpp
```

I get the following error:

```
/home/rrogers/tmp.cpp: In constructor ‘Child<ModelT>::Child(int)’:
/home/rrogers/tmp.cpp:9:18: error: class ‘Child<ModelT>’ does not have any field named ‘Parent’
   Child(int i) : Parent(i) {}
                  ^
```

Comment: It would be `Parent<ModelT>(i)` and missing type for `Child` in `main` too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
template <typename ModelT>
class Parent {
protected:
  Parent(int i) {}
};

template <typename ModelT>
class Child : public Parent<ModelT> {
public:
  Child(int i) : Parent<ModelT>(i) {}
};

int main() {
  Child<int> c(42);
}
```

There were two main problems with your code.

1. Access Specifier.
   The default access specifier for classes in C++ is private and as such the Parent constructor is not visible to the Child class. If we add a specifier of public or protected to Parent then class Child will be able to access it. As you have not specified whether Parent class objects will be created I thought it best to err on the side of caution and use the more restricted protected access specifier.
2. Templated Class
   The type of a templated class includes the template type specifier.
   In your original code it was missing is a couple of places.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Ok. I added a short explanation.

Answer (score 4):

The issue is `Parent` is not a type, it is a class template.  In order to use it you need to specify the template in order for it to spit out a actual class type like:

```
Child(int i) : Parent<ModelT>(i) {}
```

Comment: @Slava How?  Anything that derives from `Parent` cannot call its constructor since it is marked `private`.

Comment: Ah sorry, you mean Parent's ctor, I thought it is about `Parent` inherited by `Child` as private. Anyway you may remove that as OP changed his question.

Comment: @Slava Blew it all out since the corrections were made to the question.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yeah I figured since OP intended to ask a question on one topic, might as well get rid of all the unrelated errors... sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 2):

For simple cases, just provide the correct base class:

```
Child(int i) : Parent<ModelT>(i) { }
```

For those cases where the bases is too complicated to type, you can use the injected class name of the parent. It's there, it's just that unqualified name lookup won't look in dependent base classes. But you can just qualify it:

```
Child(int i) : Child::Parent(i) { }
               ~~~~~~~
```

Comment: And the constructor must not be private.